# AWS Code Deploy - Script at specified location: scripts/validate_service.sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: aws-code-deploy

My deployments fail on last step Validate Service with error message:

The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.

[Events log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqobk.png)

No lines are selected.

My validate_service.sh contain

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # verify we can access our webpage successfully

curl -v --silent localhost:80 2>&1 | grep Welcome
```

Can someone advice what should I change ?

Answer (score 0):

Script return value matters. Yours looks good to me. I just added couple of seconds to wait until application starts up.

In case you use `bash -x` together with pipeline of commands, you better add `shopt -s pipefail` so all pipeline fails when one of the commands fails.

Checkout my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5
curl http://localhost:3009 | grep Welcome
```